# QML Keys.onReleased fire when pressing key

Tags: windows, qt, qml, mingw32

Env:

Qt 5.13 + Mingw32 + Windows 10 64bit

or

Qt 5.11 + Mingw32 + Windows 10 64bit

Demo code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Item {
        id: name
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Keys.onReleased: console.log("onReleased")
    }
}
```

Problem: QML Keys.onReleased fire when pressing key(Any Key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From running your example I assume your problem occurs after holding the Key.

To prevent that you can simply check the [`isAutoRepeat`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-keyevent.html#isAutoRepeat-prop) attribute when you catch the `KeyEvent`:

```
Keys.onReleased: if (!event.isAutoRepeat) console.log("onReleased")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check `isAutoRepeat` from `event`

```
Item {
    id: name
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (!event.isAutoRepeat)
            console.log("released")
        else
            console.log("repeated like in a text field")
    }
}
```